# Is there a way to save a component instance

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a page which have tabs to navigate between components. But must save the component instance. Because when I return to a page I don't want to re-render the component.

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'

   class TabContent extends Component {

     constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       const Component = this.props.currentTab.id
       const activeTab = <Component />
       this.state = {
         openTabs: [activeTab],
         activeTab: 0
       }
     }

     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       const index = nextProps.tabs.indexOf(nextProps.currentTab)
       if (nextProps.tabs.length > this.state.openTabs.length) {
         const Component = nextProps.currentTab.id
         const activeTab = <Component />
         this.setState({
           openTabs: this.state.openTabs.concat(activeTab),
           activeTab: index
         })
       } else {

         this.setState({
           activeTab: index
         })
       }

     }

     render() {
       const { activeTab, openTabs } = this.state
       const Component = openTabs[activeTab]
       return (
         openTabs[activeTab]
       )
     }
   }

   export default TabContent
```

Is this an anti-pattern, or something that doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done be using a `single page atom`, for example using `redux`. 
If you keep the data in the component `inner state`, it will gone when the component will render off...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was hiding all components and showing only the selected one.
The solution is [here](https://github.com/AllanHorst/ReactWithTabs/tree/feature/tab-selecter)